# Dificuldade em colocar uma cor na fonte em CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap-3

Observem o seguinte código:

```
<div class="faxa_menu">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">logo tipo</div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.faxa_menu {
    color:#fff;
    position:relative;
    top:30px;
    background: black;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 27);
    -moz-opacity: .27;
    opacity: .27;
}
.navbar {
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.navbar ul li {
    float: left;
}
.navbar ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Não consigo mudar a cor dos links no menu para branco, aceito sugestões. Estou usando `Bootstrap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloca assim:

```css
.navbar ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Fiz um [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ricardobchaves6/xx5jv3qj/1/) para você ver. No fiddle o Home some porque está com o fundo branco, basta marcar o texto que você vai ver que ele ficou com a cor branca, acredito que no seu site, com html completo, ele fica em cima da barra cinza.

Answer (score -2):

Tenta isso, fiz um teste e funcionou perfeitamente.

```
.navbar ul li a {
    color: #fff;
}
```